# Why might a Projectile hitting a KActor only call HitWall, and not ProcessTouch?

Tags: udk

I have a `Projectile` subclass that seems to work fine. It travels, does `Explode()`, etc. But when it hits one of our `KActors`, I get a `HitWall` event but *not* a `ProcessTouch` event.

So my question is, why would a colliding actor trigger `HitWall`, but not `ProcessTouch`?

Comment: I am using HitWall, but I still don't understand why ProcessTouch is not called.

Comment: Should I delete this question if there's no way I can verify what it was doing any more?

Answer (score 1):

From a [forum post](http://forums.beyondunreal.com/showthread.php?p=2464576), it seems there are a few default settings that need to be changed in order to get all the events. Setting `bBlockActors=false` and `BlockActors=false` appeared to solve this problem for someone else experiencing a similar problem.